# How to disable the checkbox in loop in jquery and php dynamically

Tags: php, jquery, html

First of all, sorry for my English; I have a form where I have a main checkbox that is in loop fetched from table, and inner check box related to main checkbox.

My question is: if I check main checkbox then only the parent check box should be enabled, and if I checked one child checkbox other checkbox should be disable only under checked parent checkbox an so on. I'm just able to do this so far as I'm new to jQuery, if any one have the solution it will be appricated.

```
     $('input[class^="class"]').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.is(".class1")) {
            if ($(".class1:checked").length > 0) {
                $(".class3").prop({ disabled: false, checked: false });
            } else {
                $(".class3").prop("disabled", true);
            }
        } if ($this.is(".class3")) {
            if ($this.is(":checked")) {
                $(".class3").not($this).prop({ disabled: true, checked: false });

            } else {
                $(".class3").prop("disabled", false);
            }
        }

});


<ul>
    <?php for($i=0; $i<=2; $i++){?>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" class="class1" value="Checkbox1" />Checkbox1</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" class="class3" value="Checkbox2" disabled="disabled" />Checkbox2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" class="class3" value="Checkbox3" disabled="disabled" />Checkbox2</a></li>

</ul>
</li><?php }?>
```

Comment: That quote... ``} `if ($this.is(".class3")) {``

Comment: please correct code as suggested by @AndreasFurster and please share a jsfiddle to clarify the problem.

Comment: i update code as per your requirement. please check it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this**

**Jquery code**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[class^="class1"]').click(function() {

            var $this = $(this);
            var data_id = $this.attr('data-id');

            if ($this.is(".class1")) {
                if ($(".class1:checked").length > 0) {
                    $(".class3"+data_id).prop({ disabled: false, checked: false });
                } else {
                    $(".class3"+data_id).prop("disabled", true);
                }
            } 
    });
       $('.subcheck').click(function() {
       var val=$(this).attr("data-id");

       if($(".sub"+val).is(":checked"))
       {
         $(".sub"+val).prop("disabled", true);
         $(this).prop("disabled", false);
       }
      else
      {
        $(".sub"+val).prop("disabled", false);
      }
     });
       });
```

**Html code**

```
 <ul>
    <?php for($i=0; $i<=2; $i++){?>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="mainchk" data-id="<?php echo $i; ?>" class="class1" value="Checkbox1" />Checkbox1</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" data-id="<?php echo $i; ?>" class="subcheck  class3<?php echo $i; ?> sub<?php echo $i; ?>" value="Checkbox2" disabled="disabled" />Checkbox2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" data-id="<?php echo $i; ?>" class="subcheck class3<?php echo $i; ?> sub<?php echo $i; ?>" value="Checkbox3" disabled="disabled" />Checkbox2</a></li>

</ul>
</li><?php }?>
</ul>
```

Comment: your code working as i wanted but can you do one more thing dat if a child checkbox is checked  other child checkbox should become disabled only under the chekced parent checkbox. i will mark your answer as accepted answer than you

Comment: @ankur Bhadania Many thanks to both of you...this code is working very well :)

Answer (score 0):

@RameshSingh, always break your codes to reusable and simple functions, here i create your ideal Tree of checkboxs with simple and reusable functions...

**You can see the result [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/09zrfvnm/22/). ;)**

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="parentList" style="margin-top:50px;">   
  <li>
    <a href="#">
         <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="parentChbox" class="chbox" value="1"  />Checkbox1
    </a>
  </li>
<ul id="childList">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" class="chbox childchbox" value="2" />Checkbox2
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" class="chbox childchbox" value="3" />Checkbox2
        </a>
    </li>
 </ul>
</ul>
```

**JS and jQuery Functions:**

```
    $('input[class*="chbox"]').click(function() {

    var $this = $(this);

    var $parentCheckbox=$("input#parentChbox");
    var $parentCheckboxIsChecked=$("input#parentChbox:checked");
    var $childrenCheckboxs = $("#childList  input.childchbox");

    if ($this.is) {
        if ($parentCheckboxIsChecked.length>0) {
             disableCheckboxs($childrenCheckboxs);           
        } else {
             enableCheckboxs($childrenCheckboxs);
            var $checkedChild = checkedChild($childrenCheckboxs);            
            if (typeof $checkedChild !== "undefined")
                disableAndUncheckedAllCheckboxsElse($checkedChild,$childrenCheckboxs)             
        }
    }
});

function disableAndUncheckedAllCheckboxsElse(elseCheckbox,allCheckboxs){
    disableAndUncheckedCheckboxs(allCheckboxs);
    $(elseCheckbox).prop({ disabled: false, checked: true });
}

function checkedChild(checkboxs){
    var x;    
    checkboxs.each(function(){
        if ($(this).prop( "checked" ))
            x= this;
    });
    return x;
}
function disableCheckboxs(checkboxs){
    checkboxs.each(function(){
        $(this).prop({ disabled: true });
    });
}
function disableAndUncheckedCheckboxs(checkboxs){
    checkboxs.each(function(){
        $(this).prop({ disabled: true, checked: false });
    });
}
function enableCheckboxs(checkboxs){
    checkboxs.each(function(){
        $(this).prop("disabled", false);
    });
}
```

---

**Update:**

I added an initializing part to the client script side (jQuery) to set the defalut state of them by javascript (jquery). you can do this server side (a loop in php) + client side (below jquery) together for a safe result;

**you can see the result [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/09zrfvnm/22/)**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //Initialising the tree nodes
    var $parentCheckbox =  $("input#parentChbox");
    var $childrenCheckboxs = $("#childList  input.childchbox");

    disableAndUncheckedCheckboxs($childrenCheckboxs);
    $parentCheckbox.prop({checked: true});    
});
```

....................[image]....................

Comment: i wanted the child checkboxes  to be disabled default and will be enable only if the Parent checbox is checked that also i mentioned should be in loop. i saw your fiddle but i done dat alreay just in loop its not happening thank you

Comment: i recommend you to use loop in PHP and disableAndUncheckedCheckboxs function on CLIENT_LOAD_PAGE that i wrote ««together»» to initialize the default disable state of your children checkboxs. Using of my function on CLIENT_PAGE_LOAD is easy. i will edit my answer to show.

Comment: @RameshSingh, i tried to explain some good methods to you solve your JavaScript & jQuery problems (by slice it to small useful parts of codes). you can give UpVote to the answers which helped you... be happy... ;)